# Computing the least common multiple of the numbers 1 through n for incremental n

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, prime-factorization, conjectures

I notice a pattern when computing the least common multiple for the numbers 1 through n as we incrementally increase `n`.

The pattern is that the list of factors does not increase unless the incremental next value we include is a [prime number to a positive integer power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_power). Also, if it does increase, it only ever increases by 1.

Consider the following python code. Notice that when we include 13, the factor list begins to include 13 because 13 is a prime raised to the first power. Notice that when we include 16, the factor list begins to include an additional `2` because 16 is a prime raised to the fourth power.

```
>>> factors(lcm(*range(1,13)))
[2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 7, 11]
>>> factors(lcm(*range(1,14)))
[2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
>>> factors(lcm(*range(1,15)))
[2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
>>> factors(lcm(*range(1,16)))
[2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
>>> factors(lcm(*range(1,17)))
[2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
>>> factors(lcm(*range(1,18)))
[2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17]
>>> factors(lcm(*range(1,19)))
[2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17]
>>> factors(lcm(*range(1,20)))
[2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
```

Does the conjecture have a name, and is it true?

Stated in another way, we can always construct n+1 by *rummaging* around among the factors of the numbers 1 through n unless n+1 is a prime power. Further, if it *is* a prime power, the prime factorization of `n+1` will always have just one additional factor than our previous budget had (e.g. 2^4 vs 2^3).

(for what it's worth, I was motivated to think about this because of a recent post from Fermat's Library: https://www.linkedin.com/posts/fermatslibrary_heres-a-surprising-appearance-of-e-the-activity-7101876060991950848-D7T-)

Comment: This is certainly a true fact. To prove it, you can prove the following statement: if $n$ is composite, then $n$ divides lcm$[1,2,\dots,n-1]$.

Comment: @GregMartin you say "if  is composite, then  divides lcm[1,2,…,−1]" but 16 is composite and it doesn't divide lcm of 1 thru 15 inclusive:
```
>>> lcm(*range(1,16)) / 16
```
This returns 22522.5. Perhaps you meant to say "if $n$ is not a Prime power", but this is just a restatement of the original conjecture.

Comment: Sorry, "composite" isn't the right word—I should say "not a prime power", as you've observed.

Comment: $lcm(1,\cdots ,n)$ is divisible by every positive integer $p\le n$ , in particular by every prime and every prime power not exceeding $n$.

Comment: A change of the value occurs in fact exactly at the prime powers.

Comment: Apparently , "range" does not include the end-points.